# advanced filter w/ 1 row above

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

**UPDATE - this was resolved with:**

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A‌​3)))
```

**As an advanced filter criteria.**
The goal was to find 225522 on the second row, and pull the row above it which was accomplished with the above along with the row containing 225522.

---

**Original question**

I have several thousand lines on an excel sheet and each second line has a header line labelled USD. I need to filter to find all of the 225522 rows but I need to include the row above it with the USD.

Example:

```
USD
11111.222222.333
USD
11111.225522.333
USD
11111.222222.333
USD
11111.222222.333
USD
11111.225522.333
```

I can filter 225522 and usd, but that would just unfilter all of the rows with 222222 leaving me to manually delete thousands of USD rows. It looks like the below...

```
USD
USD
11111.225522.333
USD
USD
USD
11111.225522.333
```

But I need it to look like

```
USD
11111.225522.333
USD
11111.225522.333
```

Is there a way to filter 225522 and keep the row above it to achieve my example above?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What are you using to filter? Do you have code to provide us where the issue is occurring?

Comment: ...What exactly do you want me to elaborate? There isn't any code. I'm asking if it's possible. I thought my question was pretty straight forward. I simply want to filter the rows that contain 225522, but also keep one row above it that contains the word USD.

Comment: Use an advanced filter with formula criteria like: `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A3)))` where A2 is the first row of data in the relevant column and A3 is the second.

Comment: @rory why not place that as an answer?  Beats the crap out of what I was suggesting in my books.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not using the filtering correctly, but it is only returning the rows with 225522 instead of the rows with 225522(a2) AND the row right above it with USD(A1).

Comment: Insert a blank line at the top of your data so that data starts at row 2 and try again.

Comment: Is 1111.222222.333 the only other option for amounts?

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, I made sure that there was a blank line above my data. The filter still only pulls the rows with 225522 instead of the rows with 225522 AND the row right above it.

Comment: Nevermind @ForwardEd I got it. My issue was that I was starting the criteria on A2 (Where USD is located) instead of A3(Where 225522 is located). After moving it to A3 and making sure A2 was blank, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use an advanced filter with formula criteria like:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("225522",A‌​3)))
```

where A2 is the first row of data in the relevant column and A3 is the second row.

Answer (score 0):

This is may or may not fit your definition of filter.

In an unused portion of your sheet or in a new sheet use the forllowing formula assuming that your data is in the range A3:A2003

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$2003)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("22522",$A$3:$A$2003)),ROW(A1))
```

That will generate a list of row numbers that match your criteria.  What you want to do now is have ROW(A1), increase by 1 every two rows it gets copied down.  Then you will want to put an if statement in that so that if ROW(A1) is odd, your use the row number -1 to get your USD. and if even that you leave the row number alone.  Now tie that in with INDEX and you will generate the list you are looking for.

so to get it to count every second row increasing by 1 we could use something like:

```
=INT((ROW(A1)+1)/2)
```

This would turn our formula into:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$2003)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("22522",$A$3:$A$2003)),INT((ROW(A1)+1)/2))
```

in order to get our -1 to the row number we could incorporate something like:

```
=-ISODD(ROW(A1))
```

incorporating that into the previous formula would result in:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$2003)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("22522",$A$3:$A$2003)),INT((ROW(A1)+1)/2))-ISODD(ROW(A1))
```

The above could also have been achieved with an if statement but I decided to take a short cut.

The last step will be to incorporate it into an INDEX formula.  which will wind up looking like:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$2003)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("22522",$A$3:$A$2003)),INT((ROW(A1)+1)/2))-ISODD(ROW(A1)))
```

Now you have the formula, you just need to copy it down as far as you need to go.  It will start spewing errors when you run out of acceptable rows.

Alternatively you can set it up to display "" when there is an error/it runs out of rows by using the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$2003)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("22522",$A$3:$A$2003)),INT((ROW(A1)+1)/2))-ISODD(ROW(A1))),"")
```

The draw back to this method is that it performs array like calculations.  As such you should limit its use to a defined range and not full column references within the AGGREGATE function.  Having said that the Advanced filter option listed in your comments seems much simpler and probably a hell of a lot faster.

### UPDATE

Since you need to pull multiple columns, I would adjust your INDEX portion of the formula.  Now assuming your criteria column (column where the 225522 is located) is column F I would modify your formula as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$2:$F$4401)/ISNUMB‌​ER(SEARCH("225222",$‌​F$2:$F$4401)),INT((R‌​OW(A1)+1)/2))-ISODD(‌​ROW(A1))),"")
```

Now in order to return the same row but different columns there are two ways to approach this.  Either change the $F:$F to the appropriate column for each column you want to return or change the range from F:F to F:P and add a column reference to the index.  This following method works if the 11 columns are side by side. Other wise you will either have to assign a manual column reference that covers your range or use a match function to match column headers over the same range.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F:$P,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$2:$F$4401)/ISNUMB‌​ER(SEARCH("225222",$‌​F$2:$F$4401)),INT((R‌​OW(A1)+1)/2))-ISODD(‌​ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

The reason you see me using A1 with ROW() or COLUMN() is that I am using it as a counter that starts at 1.  So no real harm leaving it at F1 for row references as it is really only important that the row start at 1.  conversely COLUMN(A1) can really be any row from column A as I am only interested in starting at 1.  If you have to manually index because your columns are not side by side, replace COLUMN(A1) with an integer that represents the column number you want starting from the first column reference in the index range.  So in the case of the formula above F:P, start counting from F.

Comment: I did not have your column range so I assumed F:P were your 11 columns

Comment: Thanks. I used Rory's advanced criteria to solve this.